# Date column import issue

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

One of the column in csv file has date column. My date format is DD-Mon-YY. I getting "gdk-05058 non-numeric character found" issue. Can anyone solve this issue please. I need to import this date column

Comment: look at all of your data, somewhere in the DD or YY section, it's finding something other than numbers